# Magento 2.2 admin grid does not show data

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, grid, magento2.2

I try to make simple module, where customer send posts and admin can show these in the backend.

I tried do this like here:
http://techjeffyu.com/blog/magento-2-a-full-magento-2-module?tag=Magento2
or here:
http://www.mage-world.com/blog/grid-and-form-in-magento-2-admin-panel-part-1.html

I make everything like in instruction, but it doesn't work. It should works.

There is my module code:
https://github.com/dominik04u/MagentoSimpleModule

I can't find what I do wrong.

Comment: Please read through this website: [http://techjeffyu.com/blog/magento-2-create-uicomponent-list-and-uicomponent-form-by-example](http://techjeffyu.com/blog/magento-2-create-uicomponent-list-and-uicomponent-form-by-example)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/133752)